# How to have Chrome show true image size?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I can't seem to have Chrome browser show the true image size via `<img>`
and also by `drawImage` via `canvas` context. Explorer shows both of these 
correctly.

In Chrome, the image shown is not by the dimensions of the original image 
but a scaled down one. The browser when rendered from a Web server seems to 
have something to do with it.  Curiously enough, when open the browser on 
the html file locally:

E.g. `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Website_TEST_active/test1.html`, the image dimensions are correct.

Attached is a stripped down HTML and Javascript code. Appreciate any insights.

Thanks
Sean

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Image to use:</p>
            <img id="scream" onload="loadImage()" src="pics/cover.jpg" alt="Test">
            <p>Canvas:</p>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="854" height="480" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
                Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            </canvas>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                // Not used
            }
            /*
            * Upon image load, draw image on canvas
            */ 
            function loadImage(){
                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                var img = document.getElementById("scream");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
                console.log("Original Image W=" + img.naturalWidth +
                            " H=" + img.naturalHeight); 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might be right for what you're asking.

Here's the link- https://superuser.com/a/364875

> Open Developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I or use the Settings Icon at the
>   top-right of your browser window => Tools => Developer tools) and on
>   the relevant page, switch to the Network tab and reload the page.
>   In the Size column you'll see the size of everything loaded
>   (Documents, Stylesheets, Images, Scripts, ...). You can enable a
>   filter to help you find out what you need - at the bottom-center of
>   Developer tools frame.